# 2 монитора linux, ошибка за пределы 1600x1600

Tags: графика, linux

При попытке подключить и расширить рабочие пространство выдает вот такую фиговину:

[image]

У меня на ноуте разрешение 1366х768 рядом монитор стоит, хочу ему дать разрешение 1024х768. Где это ограничение можно изменить?

Comment: за настройки видео отвечает xorg.conf,попробуй его поковырять

Answer (score 2):

[X.Org/Dual Monitors](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/HOWTO_Dual_Monitors) - всё вроде вполне доходчиво...